# reusing textview vs new declarations

Tags: android

Is there anything to gain from reusing a textveiew? There code is more readable when not reusing. Is there any difference in these two ways of use besides the code is more readable when making new declarations? Especially when there are alot of textviews

reuse example

```
TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
tv.setText("tv1");
tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv2);
tv.setText("tv2");
```

new declarations example

```
TextView tv1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
tv1.setText("tv1");
TextView tv2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv2);
tv2.setText("tv2");
```

Comment: I guess there is less memory consumption when reusing since i only have 1 textview in memory at a time, but i was kinda looking for speed :)

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the memory, if you are not going to use `tv(TextView Object)` anywhere in the code then first approach is better otherwise 2nd one is good.

Answer (score 0):

findViewById(..) is an operation which you dont want to do everytime you need to access the TextView, hence it is advised to initialize a TextView

Comment: Well, the problem is that i have a viewpager with a some views that contain 5-10 textview and most of them are displaying static data that i get from a server, hence i need to use findViewById in my instantiateItem method in the viewpager. I was hoping that one of these methods could boost performance, and anything is better than nothing

Comment: For performance purpose you should cache TextViews so that you dont have to do findViewById(...) every time

Comment: Well, Android handles caching of views by itself, so i wouldnt want to interfer with that

Answer (score -2):

Nope, won't make any difference at all

Comment: What do you base your answer on? Do you have a link to a post somewhere that explains this?